# Dynamically add date as column header

Tags: jquery, datatable

I want to have dynamic column header and column data in my data table. For example, I have date picker and I choose date between February 10, 2019 to February 12, 2019 So my data table will have

```
February 10, 2019 |  February 11, 2019 |  February 12, 2019
```

as column header. How to achieve this output?

This is how I construct my datatable

```js
$("#tblClients").DataTable({
  paginate: true,
  pagingType: "full_numbers",
  lengthChange: true,
  filter: true,
  info: true,
  autoWidth: false,
  columnDefs: [{
    autoWidth: true,
    "targets": [1]
  }, {
    "targets": [2, 3, 4, 5],
    "sortable": false
  }],
  "oSearch": {
    "bSmart": false
  },
  "dom": 'Bfrtip',
  "buttons": [{
    "extend": 'excelHtml5',
    "text": 'Download',
    "className": "btn btn-success",
  }],
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" />
<table id="tblClients" class="table table-hover table-bordered">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>No.</th>
      <th>Client</th>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Email Address</th>
      <th>No. of Login</th>
      <th>Last Logon Time</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <?php foreach($logData as $key => $log): ?>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <?php echo $key+1; ?>
      </td>
      <td>
        <?php echo $log['client']; ?>
      </td>
      <td>
        <?php echo $log['name']; ?>
      </td>
      <td>
        <?php echo $log['email']; ?>
      </td>
      <td>
        <?php echo $log['counter']; ?>
      </td>
      <td data-sort="<?php echo $log['created']; ?>">
        <?php
          date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Manila');
          echo date(DATE_FORMAT.' H:i:s', strtotime($log['created']));
        ?>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: I created a snippet for you. Please replace the PHP with rendered HTML - unless you believe it is a PHP issue

Comment: hi @mplungjan where is the snippet

Comment: Somone else edited your question. I will add it back

Comment: You likely want to add `<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" /><script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>` to after the jquery

Comment: Are we looking for a jquery solution or a php solution?

Comment: @AlyssaAndreaArce Please come back and enlighten us. Too many questions. The first is "Do you want a PHP solution or jQuery ONLY solution" If the latter, please REPLACE your PHP with pure rendered HTML

Comment: @mplungjan hi sorry late reply i want it in jquery way.

Comment: @AlyssaAndreaArce Soooo - please click [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/54644174/edit), then scroll down and click "edit the above snippet" and replace the PHP with a table containing enough data to create a [mcve] - maybe add an image to show where the column headers are to go

Comment: Your tables is not showing any date. Do you mean user the hidden data-sort with the $log['created'])  - where do you want the columns?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `title` property of `columns` option to set the datatable headers dynamically:

```
// Create a dynamic range of columns
var columns = [];  
for (var i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {      
    var date = new Date(2019,1,i);
    columns.push({
        title: date.getDate() + '/' + (date.getMonth() + 1) + '/' + date.getFullYear(),
        data: 'dateData_' + i
  });
}

var myTable = $('#example').DataTable({    
    data: dataset,
    columns: columns
});
```

Check this [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/kapantzak/fsaqc2j9/15/)

Comment: Why not post a snippet here instead of a fiddle??

Comment: I have a question regarding this one, if we were to add a new column aside from date, how will we do it?