# Dynamically add date as column header with name and id

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, ajax, datatable

I was following this guide [Dynamically add date as column header](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54644174/dynamically-add-date-as-column-header#), but my problem is that I cannot add new column, I want to add **Name**, **Age**, and **Section** before the dynamic date.

Is there a way to do this?

based on this [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/kapantzak/fsaqc2j9/15/).

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {

    var dataset = [
    { 
       Name: 'John',
       Age: '21',
       Section : 'One',
        dateData_1: 'Date A1',
      dateData_2: 'Date A2',
      dateData_3: 'Date A3',
      dateData_4: 'Date A4',
      dateData_5: 'Date A5',
    },
    { 
       Name: 'Doe',
       Age: '22',
       Section : 'Two',
        dateData_1: 'Date B1',
      dateData_2: 'Date B2',
      dateData_3: 'Date B3',
      dateData_4: 'Date B4',
      dateData_5: 'Date B5',
    },
    { 
       Name: 'Smith',
       Age: '23',
       Section : 'Three',
        dateData_1: 'Date C1',
      dateData_2: 'Date C2',
      dateData_3: 'Date C3',
      dateData_4: 'Date C4',
      dateData_5: 'Date C5',
    },
    { 
       Name: 'Mark',
       Age: '24',
       Section : 'Four',
        dateData_1: 'Date D1',
      dateData_2: 'Date D2',
      dateData_3: 'Date D3',
      dateData_4: 'Date D4',
      dateData_5: 'Date D5',
    },
    { 
       Name: 'Kane',
       Age: '25',
       Section : 'Five',
        dateData_1: 'Date E1',
      dateData_2: 'Date E2',
      dateData_3: 'Date E3',
      dateData_4: 'Date E4',
      dateData_5: 'Date E5',
    }
  ]

    var columns = [];  
  for (var i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {    
    var date = new Date(2019,1,i);
    columns.push({
        title: date.getDate() + '/' + (date.getMonth() + 1) + '/' + date.getFullYear(),
      data: 'dateData_' + i
    });
  }

  var myTable = $('#example').DataTable({    
    data: dataset,
    columns: columns
  });

});
</script>

<div class="container">
  <table id="example">
    <thead></thead>
    <tbody></tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

I want to add loop before the dynamic date, the columns **Name**, **Age**, and **Section**,

[image]

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you are filling the data source array but totally forgot to fill columns list.
Just add **Name**, **Age** and **Section** to the 'columns' array like and that's it!

```
  var columns = [
    { title: "Name", data: 'Name' },
    { title: "Age", data: 'Age' },
    { title: "Section", data: 'Section' }
  ];
```

Here is an example: http://jsfiddle.net/pzxgbqdf/